# Single pole circuit breaker won't close unless double pole above it is closed

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I was trying to find out where a trip was in my house and turned off a double-pole breaker then a single-pole breaker. Went in reverse order to turn the single-pole breaker back on and it would trip back open immediately. Only when I closed the double-pole breaker would the single-pole breaker close. Is this a serious problem?

Comment: Sounds like a serious problem to me.  You should probably contact a local licensed Electrician.

Comment: I already have my uncle coming next week for something else and he is licensed. I didn't want to spring it on him without knowing how serious of an issue it is. It has been like this for 17 years so...

Comment: It's serious. How hard it is to fix will depend on where the short circuit turns out to be. You want to send this description to him before he travels, so he can make sure to bring the appropriate tools.